# css animation help needed

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

So I am Pretty new to programming and I just started with html, css, JavaScript and a bit of php. I've tried to make a dropdown menu with animations. It works prety god but now i want to add "reverse" animations for the menu Options but i can't get it to work without playing the "fade out" Animation when the Options are loaded. I hope my Problem is clear enought and I'm Looking Forward to find someone who can help me out with my problem.   ps: I'm german so sorry for grammar mistakes ;)

index.html:

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/simplyblu_j1.5/css/template.css"/>
  <head>
    <title>Stephen's Site</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="menu1"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/stephen.scholz/"><font color="c079da">Instagram</font></a></div>
    <div id="menu2"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCGJPfjc2i8qOVuEhChVYhBg?view_as=subscriber"><font color="da5148">Youtube</font></a></div>
    <div id="menu3"><a href="https://twitter.com/_stephen_scholz"><font color="68b9e1">Twitter</font></a></div>
    <div id="menu4"><a href="menutest.html"><font color="000">Menutest V2</font></a></div>
    <div id="bild1"></div>
    <div id="link1"><a href="testing.html"><font color=000">Menutest V1</font></a></div>
<!--    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown-button">
        <a href="">Menu</a>
        </div>
        <ul>
          <li>Spalte 1</li>
          <li>Spalte 2</li>
          <li>Spalte 3</li>
          <li>Spalte 4</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        -->
    <div id="credit1"><font color="d97757--">Made by Stephen Scholz</font></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

"menutest.html"(where the Dropdown items are in):

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/simplyblu_j1.5/css/template3.css"/>
  <head>
    <title>Stephen's Site</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown-button">
        <a href="">Menu</a></div>
        <ul class="opt">
          <li><a href="index.html"><font color="000"<div id="opt1">Hauptseite</font></a></li>
          <li><a href="index.html"><font color="000"<div id="opt2">Hauptseite2</font></a></li>
          <li><a href="index.html"><font color="000"<div id="opt3">Hauptseite3</font></a></li>
          <li><a href="index.html"><font color="000"<div id="opt4">Hauptseite4</font></a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    <div id="credit1"><font color="d97757--">Made by Stephen Scholz</font></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

template3.css (css file for Dropdown menu) :

````
    background-image: url(../images/background.png);
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: #F9EBAE;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;

}
#credit1 {
    font-size: 25px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 3400px;
    border: 3px solid #cfcecf;
}
.dropdown{
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 150px;
}
.dropdown-button {
    padding: 10px;
    background: white;
}
.dropdown-button a{
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
    *border: 3px solid #cfcecf;
}
.dropdown ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    background: white;
    *border: 3px solid #cfcecf;
  animation: load 1s forwards;
}
.dropdown ul li{
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    *background: white;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
  animation: load 1s forwards
}
.dropdown:hover li{
    animation: load 0.3s forwards;
    display: block;
}
@keyframes load {
    0%{
        transform: scale(0) translateX(100px) rotate(-45deg);
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1) translateX(0px) rotate(0);
        /*box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;*/
    }
  0%{
    transform: scale(0) translateX(100px) rotate(-45deg);
  }
}
#opt1:hover {
  animation: opt 0.5s forwards;
  display: block;
}
#opt2:hover {
  animation: opt 0.5s forwards;
  display: block;
}
#opt3:hover {
  animation: opt 0.5s forwards;
  display: block;
}
#opt4:hover {
  animation: opt 0.5s forwards;
  display: block;
}
@keyframes opt{
  0%{
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100%{
    transform: scale(1.4);
  }
}
#opt1 {
  animation: optout 1s forwards;
  display: block;
  }
#opt2 {
  animation: optout 1s forwards;
  display: block;
  }
#opt3 {
  animation: optout 1s forwards;
  display: block;
  }
#opt4 {
  animation: optout 1s forwards;
  display: block;
  }

@keyframes optout {
  0%{
    transform: scale(1.4);
  }
  100%{
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}```
````

Comment: do u want to have reverse animation while leaving the menu option?

Comment: I want it while leaving the id's (opt1,opt2,opt3 and opt4) but not when the Dropdown (Animation: load 1s Forwards) opens up, I don't know if that's possible but if yes I would be realy happy. Also I want to stick with the keyframes and not with `@keyframes optout :{from...to…}